# Cannot select and copy value of html element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to copy value from one div to some input. When trying to display selected value it shows `undefined`. Why?

```
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail2">  
    <div class="book author"> Author One </div>

</div>
```

--

```
// $('#author').val(   $('#thumbnail'+id+' .author').val()            ); // copy
alert (   $('#thumbnail'+id+' .book .author').val() ); // displays 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the space between .book and .author (you are currently selecting for an element with the class 'author' which is a child of an element with a class of 'book') and use `text()` not `val()`, so

`alert($('#thumbnail'+id+' .book.author').text());`

Answer (score 1):

`div` don't have `values`

use `.html()` or `.text()`

```
alert($('#thumbnail'+id+' .author').html());
```